# arrange buttons in an array in a layout

Tags: android, arrays, button, android-linearlayout

[image: buttons to be arranged in center of the layout]I have four buttons in a screen which i want to arrange in the center of the screen, and nine buttons in the next screen which should be arranged in the center  of the screen and so on.. i used linear layout but iam not getting the desired layout.
below is my xml..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.go123.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingStart="10dip"
android:paddingEnd="10dip"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Go 1,2,3.." />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Go 1,2,3.." />

       <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button0"
    android:text="Go 1,2,3.." />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Go 1,2,3.." />
```

I also tried to use Android Flexbox Layout but without success..

All I got is this image..[image: Only three buttons shown!]

Comment: u need buttons to be vertically placed?

Comment: add a snapshot of the result you are looking for. A simple sketch on paper would do fine.

Comment: @Ritesh added a snopshot of the desired result..

Comment: @jagapathi i need buttons to be as in calculator.. centered inside a layout..

Comment: then use gridlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SCREEN ONE:**

**1.** Use `RelativeLayout` as root layout and add child vertical `LinearLayout` and make it `center` aligned by using attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

**2.** Add another two horizontal `LinearLayout` inside above `LinearLayout`.

**3.** Put `Button's` inside horizontal `LinearLayout's`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- ROW 1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 2"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 3"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 4"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**SCREEN_TWO:**

**1.** Use `RelativeLayout` as root layout and add child vertical `LinearLayout` and make it `center` aligned by using attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

**2.** Add another three horizontal `LinearLayout` inside above `LinearLayout`.

**3.** Put `Button's` inside horizontal `LinearLayout's`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- ROW 1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 2"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 3"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 4"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 5"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 6"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- ROW 3 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 7"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 8"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 9"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**FYI,** you can change `Button` heights as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

**For screen 1 design use this**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.ap.rythunestam.HomeActivity">

   <TableLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="button 1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           </RelativeLayout>
           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content">
               <Button
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:text="button 2"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           </RelativeLayout>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content">
               <Button
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:text="button 3"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           </RelativeLayout>
           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content">
               <Button
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:text="button 4"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           </RelativeLayout>
       </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**[image]

For screen modify the same code for 9 buttons hope that helps